# Logging into website with requests

Tags: python, httprequest

I have this form, but I am not sure how to create the payload that will do this correctly.

```
<form method="post" action="/login" name="loginform" id="loginForm">
    <fieldset id="fs">
        <label for="username">Username:
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        </label>

        <label for="password">Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        </label>

        <input type="hidden" name="act" value="login" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I tried doing `payload = {"username":"blah","password":"blah"}; r=requests.post(url, data=payload)` but I didn't get the response I was expecting; namely, `r.text` doesn't have the expected "Login failed" line in it.
But when I fill out the form and try to log in for the first time through a browser, it indicated that it was my second failed login.

The website I'm playing with in particular is www.thepiratebay.se, and what I'm working towards is being able to programmatically upload a torrent file.

**---EDIT---**

The new code I am using is

```
import requests
user = "username"
pswd = "password"
url = "http://www.thepiratebay.se/login"
payload = {
    "act":"login",
    "username":user,
    "password":pswd,
    "submit":"Login"
}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
print r.text
```

Still not working! `r.text` is just the default login page. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: You didn't include the `act` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a different module, twill, to do what I wanted. I think twill is actually a 'full' web browser. Anyway, this is what the code turned into:

```
from twill import commands
commands.go("http://www.thepiratebay.se/login")
commands.form("loginform", "username", "blah")
commands.form("loginform", "password", "blah")
commands.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

use firebug net tab to track down the actual sent parameters, this is what I got when I gave it a try:

```
act          login
password     password
submit       Login
username     username

Source
username=username&password=password&act=login&submit=Login
```